# How to put the head element at the back of a queue?

Tags: c, queue

I need your input on something: I need to know how to put the HEAD element of a queue at the back (tail) of a queue? I know how to put an element in a queue, but I don't know how to put an already inserted head element at the back of a queue. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Dequeue it then enqueue it. (Or pop it, then push it... those terms are fine to use for queues.)

This will take it off of the head (the front), and put it at the back.

Comment: Aren't pop and push for stacks?
Also, dequeuing the head then enqueuing the element back doesn't seem to work.

Comment: What the operations defined for your queue? Ah.. you're using dequeue/enqueue. That's probably clearer. However, people *do* use the words push and pop to refer to these operations as well. It's unambiguous what it means since you can only take from one place and put in one place in a queue.

Answer (score 0):

Queues uses the `FIFO` (First In First Out) data structure. In this structure the removed element is always in the head and the added element is put always in the tail of the queue. So if you want to migrate the head element to the tail of the queue you just need to remove a element from the queue and add the same element to the queue again.